# How to find number of speaker in a recorded mp3 file? Find how many speakers are there

Tags: json, api, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I am working on Interview sentiment analysis code in which I need to convert a recorded interview file(mp3) to text and from text data I need to find emotions of the candidate.

But the problem is when I converted mp3 file to text using IBM watson speech to text API it is showing the text data of the both interviewer and interviewee.

So, how to find different number of person in the file? And how to find text data of particular interviewee?

I wrote this code, help me

```
import json
from os.path import join, dirname
from ibm_watson import SpeechToTextV1
from ibm_watson.websocket import RecognizeCallback, AudioSource

from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator
authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('api key')
speech_to_text = SpeechToTextV1(
authenticator=authenticator
)
speech_to_text.set_service_url('url')

class MyRecognizeCallback(RecognizeCallback):
def __init__(self):
RecognizeCallback.__init__(self)

    def on_data(self, data):
        print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
    
    def on_error(self, error):
        print('Error received: {}'.format(error))
    
    def on_inactivity_timeout(self, error):
        print('Inactivity timeout: {}'.format(error))

myRecognizeCallback = MyRecognizeCallback()

with open(join(dirname(__file__), './.', 'sample_2.mp3'),'rb') as audio_file:
audio_source = AudioSource(audio_file)

speech_to_text.recognize_using_websocket(audio=audio_source,content_type='audio/mp3',recognize_callback=myRecognizeCallback,model='en-US_BroadbandModel',max_alternatives=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of speakers, I believe you should first include the `speaker_labels` parameters to True. Than you should parse the response and count the different speakers withing the `speaker_labels` key using a `set` for example to avoid counting a same speaker two times.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34257338)

Comment: @MohammadBaqer, which link ?